# How to get a table from an html page using JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, jsoup, html-parsing

I am working on a project where I am trying to fetch financial statements from the internet and use them in a JAVA application to automatically create ratios, and charts.

The site I am using uses a login and password to get to the tables.
The Tag is TBODY, but there are 2 other TBODY's in the html.

How can I use java to print my table to a txt file where I can then use in my application?
What would the best way to go about this, and what should I read up on?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If this were my project, I'd look into using an HTML parser, something like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) (although others are available). The jsoup site has a tutorial, and after playing with it a while, you'll likely find it pretty easy to use.

For example, for an HTML table like so:

[image]

jsoup could parse it like so:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class TableEg {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String html = "http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r1/topic/" +
            "com.ibm.etools.iseries.toolbox.doc/htmtblex.htm";
      try {
         Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();
         Elements tableElements = doc.select("table");

         Elements tableHeaderEles = tableElements.select("thead tr th");
         System.out.println("headers");
         for (int i = 0; i < tableHeaderEles.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(tableHeaderEles.get(i).text());
         }
         System.out.println();

         Elements tableRowElements = tableElements.select(":not(thead) tr");

         for (int i = 0; i < tableRowElements.size(); i++) {
            Element row = tableRowElements.get(i);
            System.out.println("row");
            Elements rowItems = row.select("td");
            for (int j = 0; j < rowItems.size(); j++) {
               System.out.println(rowItems.get(j).text());
            }
            System.out.println();
         }

      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Resulting in the following output:

```
headers
ACCOUNT
NAME
BALANCE

row
0000001
Customer1
100.00

row
0000002
Customer2
200.00

row
0000003
Customer3
550.00
```

Comment: If I need a password to access the html page with table, then how would I do it ? The password cannot be sent in a get request.

Comment: Hover, I'd really appreciate it if you could accept my edit which adds the code for the HTML table. Will be useful in case the url goes dead. Thanks for this excellent answer. Thank you my friend, I love you.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev: please format your HTML code to conform to standards.

Comment: Thank you hover. I am not sure I understand. Should I make it fit so that no side scrolling is needed ?