# jsoup extract elements underneath a specific tag

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to extract several elements under a specific tag
I have a bunch of `<h5>` that i want to extract with an `<h6>` and a `<table>` that are right underneath them.
The problem that I am having is:
a) I have several `<h5>` tags 
b) that the  `<h6>` and a `<table>` are not a children/siblings of the `<h5>`. so for example `h5 > table` won't work.

so what I would like to get at the end is :
From this site:
http://tcat.nextinsight.com/routes.php?mrnid=453

Route 13 Monday - Friday , the `<h6>` inbound and the table, as well as 
Route 13 Monday - Friday , the `<h6>` outbound and the table.

once I have the entire table I can use this example [How to get a table from an html page using JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771218/how-to-get-a-table-from-an-html-page-using-java) to work with the table

sample structure: (also can be found at the given url)

```
<table width="890" border="0" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="20" bgcolor="#8cd2ef" class="heading"><h6>Outbound from center of Ithaca</h6></td>
        </tr>
        <br><h5>Route 13 - Saturday</h5><tr class="tableSub"><td>Green @ Commons</td>
<td>Seneca @ Commons</td>
<td>Third @ Hancock</td>
<td>Aldi</td>
<td>Lake @ Ithaca HS</td>
<td>Stewart Park</td>
<td>Shops at Ithaca Mall @ Sears</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample structure?

Comment: yep. Also can be found at the given url http://tcat.nextinsight.com/routes.php?mrnid=453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector:

```
h5:contains(Route 13 Monday - Friday) + table
```

Used like:

```
Elements tables = doc.select("h5:contains(Route 13 Monday - Friday) + table");
```

Will get you every table that is preceded by an `<h5>` of content `"Route 13 Monday - Friday"`.

Check a working snippet using the URL you provided:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://tcat.nextinsight.com/routes.php?mrnid=453").get();
    System.out.println(doc.title());
    Elements tables = doc.select("h5:contains(Route 13 Monday - Friday) + table");
    for (Element table : tables) {
        System.out.println(table);
        System.out.println("#\n#\n#\n#");
    }
}
```